# how to find out the next character in a list in python

Tags: python

Im making a calculator and every time a button is clicked, a number is appended into the list. I want to find out the type of the next character after a character in my list in order to check if its a double digit number. I have tried this, but it doesn't seem to be working. here's the code:

```
def compound_calculation(calculation):
    for num in calculation:
        if type(calculation.index(num) + 1) == int:
            print("double digit number")
label1_list = [1, 2, 3, "+", 4, 5]
```

Comment: Could you give an example of your list?

Comment: Please: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Have a look into list slicing.  That will put you on the right track.  Additionally, look at the `isinstance()` function for type comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `isinstance(var, type)`.

For an alternative way of doing it

```py
a = ['a', 1, '2', 3, 4, '5']
filter(
  lambda x: isinstance(x[0], int) and isinstance(x[1], int), 
  zip(a, a[1:]))
```

and it will return `[(3,4)]`

Step by step:

- Offset the original list by 1:

```
a = ['a', 1, '2', 3, 4, '5']
b = a[1:] # [1, '2', 3, 4, '5']
```

- Zip the two lists into tuple pairs (current and next item). The only pair we want in this example is `(3, 4)` (two consecutive digits):

```
zip(a, b) # [('a', 1), (1, '2'), ('2', 3), (3, 4), (4, '5')]
```

- Iterate all items and check if both items in a tuple (x[0], item and x[1], next item) are both `int`s and filter out the ones who aren't

```
filter(
  lambda x: isinstance(x[0], int) and isinstance(x[1], int), 
  zip(a, a[1:]))
```

Comment: can you explain what you did here?

Comment: @sneakydude added explanation to answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
def compound_calculation(calculation):
    for i in range(len(calculation)-1):
        if isinstance(calculation[i+1],int):
            print('double digit number')
```

Comment: what is the a in a[i + 1]

Comment: Sorry for that, accidentaly did it (copying and pasting from python shell) it will be `calculation` edited